# Модернизация OpenL2TP под Linux

Tags: linux

Подскажите, как можно переделать пакет OpenL2TP под Linux или как можно сделать, чтоб он работал в этой среде?

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу сказать, что в теме, но мне кажется, что делать ничего не надо. Ведь на [сайте OpenL2TP](http://www.openl2tp.org/) написано

> OpenL2TP is an open source L2TP client / server, written specifically for Linux

А в заголовке огромными буквами написано

> a Linux L2TP solution for enterprise VPN and ISPs

Так о каких изменениях может идти речь, если всё уже и так должно работать?